Sorting a polars list[struct[]] by struct value
How do I use polars.Expr.list.sort to sort a list of structs by one of the struct values, i.e.
df = pl.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "data": [{"key": "A", "value": 2}, {"key": "B", "value": 1}]}])

I want to sort data by the value field, i.e. the result should be
df = pl.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "data": [{"key": "B", "value": 1}, {"key": "A", "value": 2}]}])

df.with_columns(pl.col("b").list.sort())

Doesn't work and list.sort doesn't accept arguments?

Indeed, pl.Expr.list.sort does not take any arguments on the comparison function used for the sorting. This seems like a reasonable feature request for polars' Github page.
Until this is implemented, I can think of 2 possible approaches.

Polars seems to sort the list primarily based on the first struct field. Hence, reordering the struct fields before sorting influences the sorting behaviour.
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("data")
        .list.eval(
            pl.struct(
                pl.element().struct.field("value"),
                pl.element().struct.field("key"),
            )
        )
        .list.sort()
    )
)

shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ data               │
│ --- ┆ ---                │
│ i64 ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [{1,"B"}, {2,"A"}] │
└─────┴────────────────────┘


Another more general approach is to explode the list column into multiple rows. Next, the frame can be sorted by the "value" field of the struct column "data" within each group defined by the column "id".
This method offers a bit more flexibility as the sorting can be done based on multiple struct fields (to handle matches) and with mixed values for the descending parameter of pl.DataFrame.sort.
(
    df
    .explode("data")
    .sort("id", pl.col("data").struct.field("value"))
    .group_by("id")
    .agg("data")
)

shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ data               │
│ --- ┆ ---                │
│ i64 ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [{"B",1}, {"A",2}] │
└─────┴────────────────────┘




you can always Expr.explode() your lists, DataFrame.sort() the DataFrame and then GroupBy.agg() results back (given that id is unique identifier of the rows):
(
    df.explode('data')
    .sort(
        'id',
        pl.col('data').struct.field('value')
    ).group_by('id').agg('data')
)

┌─────┬────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ data               │
│ --- ┆ ---                │
│ i64 ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [{"B",1}, {"A",2}] │
└─────┴────────────────────┘

Probably a bit more convenient way would be to Expr.explode() the column within the with_columns(), sort it by field of the struct and then Expr.implode() it back, something like this:
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('data').list.explode().sort_by(
        pl.col('data').list.explode().struct.field('value')
    ).implode()
)

┌─────┬────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ data               │
│ --- ┆ ---                │
│ i64 ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [{"B",1}, {"A",2}] │
└─────┴────────────────────┘


I raised a enhancement request, and github user nameexhaustion (https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/16110#issuecomment-2099552339) suggested another option:
>>> df.with_columns(
...     sorted=pl.col("data").list.eval(
...         pl.element().sort_by(pl.element().struct.field("value"))
...     )
... )
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ data               ┆ sorted             │
│ --- ┆ ---                ┆ ---                │
│ i64 ┆ list[struct[2]]    ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [{"A",2}, {"B",1}] ┆ [{"B",1}, {"A",2}] │
└─────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┘

